# Передача параметров в метку cmd

Tags: cmd

Есть такой код в Bat-файле:

```
FOR /R %BuilderDirectory% /D %%i IN (*) DO (
  If Exist %Builder% Call :Build %%i
 )

:Build(
set PathMSBuild=%1
echo %PathMSBuild%
)
```

По всем путям цикл проходится и переходит в метку, вот только параметр приходит постоянно пустой, `echo` ничего не выводит. Пытался и так передавать `Call :Build "%%i"` - тоже самое.

В чём дело?

Comment: https://rsdn.org/article/winshell/batanyca.xml

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
FOR /R %BuilderDirectory% /D %%i IN (*) DO (
  If Exist %Builder% Call :Build %%i
)
goto :eof

:Build
set PathMSBuild=%1
echo %PathMSBuild%
```

И не забыть о

> Наконец, добавлена поддержка связывания времени выполнения для переменных среды
>   окружения. По умолчанию эта поддержка отключена. Ключ /V командной строки
>   CMD.EXE позволяет включать и выключать ее. Для вызова справки, наберите CMD /?
>
> Связывание времени выполнения для переменных среды окружения полезно при обходе
>   ограничений раннего связывания, которое происходит при первом чтении текстовой
>   строки, а не при ее выполнении. Следующий пример демонстрирует возникающую
>   проблему при использовании раннего связывания переменных:
>
> `set VAR=before
>       if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>           set VAR=after
>           if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo Тело внутреннего оператора сравнения
>       )`
>
> Данное сообщение не будет выводиться, т.к. %VAR% в ОБОИХ выражениях IF
>   подставляется в момент первого использования в первом IF, в том числе и в тело
>   первого ветвления IF, которое является составным выражением. В IF внутри
>   составного выражения в действительности сравниваются значения "before" и
>   "after", что заведомо ложно. Следующий пример демонстрирует подобную ошибку:
>
> `set LIST=
>       for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
>       echo %LIST%`
>
> в данном случае список файлов текущей папки никогда не будет построен. Вместо
>   этого, значением переменной LIST будет имя последнего найденного файла.
>   И вновь, это случилось потому, что %LIST% подставляется всего один раз -
>   в момент обработки выражения FOR, когда список еще пуст.
>   Фактически, приведенный фрагмент эквивалентен следующему примеру:
>
> `for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i`
>
> в котором имя последнего найденного файла сохраняется в переменной LIST.
>
> Связывание времени выполнения для переменных среды окружения происходит при
>   использовании специального символа (восклицательного знака), обозначающего
>   проведение сопоставления во время выполнения. Если включена поддержка
>   связывания времени выполнения, то для достижения ожидаемых результатов
>   приведенные выше фрагменты должны быть изменены следующим образом:
>
> `set VAR=before
>       if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>           set VAR=after
>           if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo Тело внутреннего оператора сравнения
>       )`
>
> `set LIST=
>       for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
>       echo %LIST%`